# Efficient way for mongodb.find() to search through 1 million document?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema

I have a blog post server that will contains million of articles, and i need to be able to get all Articles written by User A.

What would be the best schema design.

1) Separate both User and Articles documents, and to get user A Articles search in all the million record for the User's id

`articles.find({Writer_id: User_A.id})`

2) Put a article id reference inside User schema. ex:

```
 userSchema = {
    name: "name",
    age: "age",
    articles: [ {type:mongoose.Article_id}, {type:mongoose.Article_id} ]
   }
```

And search for User A and make a join to get Articles back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's far better to keep the `Writer_id` approach and create an index on that property. If you store an array of references, then you'll need to perform an `$in` operation on your `find()` calls. This will result in your query "jumping" from one matching `Article_id` to another. If instead you have a `Writer_id` and an index built for that property, all of user's articles will exist in the same sequential "block" in the index, requiring no jumping around whatsoever. The result is a far more read-efficient `find()` operation.

Additionally, the articles array approach would require frequent updates to the user document, whereas the `Writer_id` approach only requires inserts. Inserts are incredibly efficient, whereas frequent updates are relatively inefficient. Finally, an array of `Article_id`s can potentially (if unlikely) result in hitting the 16 MB document size limit. The `Writer_id` approach runs into no such limitation.

The difference should be relatively negligible for a smaller project, but if you're looking for scalability, then you're better off with the `Writer_id` approach.